# How to populate an array on the direct screen using android studio so you can print from the console

Tags: java, android-studio

I would like a solution that replaces the console and shows this result right on the screen or using some tool like alert or something, is it possible?

```
for (int x = 0; x < classe; x++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
                System.out.print(tab[x][c] + " | ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like `Toast` or `Snackbar`.

```
String string = "";
for (int x = 0; x < classe; x++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            string += tab[x][c] + " | ";
        }
        string += "\n";
    }
}

// toast example
Toast.makeText(activity, string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
// snackbar example
Snackbar.make(activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content), string, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Check [this Snackbar & Toast tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/10324/android-snackbar-example-tutorial#:~:targetText=Snackbar%20in%20android%20is%20a,contain%20an%20optional%20action%20button.) for more info